# Time Complexity of inserting string to c++ stl set

Tags: c++, string, stl, set, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of inserting string to set container of c++ STL?
According to me, it should be O(xlogn), where x is length of string to be inserted and n is size of set. Also copying of string to set should be of linear in length of string. 
But this code of mine is running instantly.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    set<string> c;
    string s(100000,'a');
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        c.insert(s);
    }

}
```

Where am I wrong, shouldn't the complexity be order of 10^10?

Comment: Is it possible the compiler's optimizer removed all the code because it doesn't do anything noticeable?

Comment: See the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: You do understand that you end up inserting a grand total of one string, into your `std::set`,  and the other 99999 inserts get completely ignored, right?

Comment: Even if you change the code inside for loop to string t= s; it ran instantly. Shouldnt copying string  linear in length.

Comment: The compiler is likely optimizing most of those assignments away since it can tell that the intermediate values are not used.

Comment: I am multiplying taking in mind that string comparisions take place for each insertion which are linear in length

Comment: You are right! Note however that if the strings are random, or at least quite different, comparison will be much faster

Comment: In addition to the risk of optimization, you are creating a data set which might trivialize the sorting aspect of c++ set, since ... they're all identical. So you can't rely on the log term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *use* the `set` in some way to reduce the risk of the loop getting optimized away, for example by adding `return c.size();`.

Also your choice of the number of iterations might be too low. Add a digit to the loop counter and you will see a noticeable run time.

A modern CPU can easily process >2*10<sup>9</sup> ops/s. Assuming your compiler uses `memcmp`, which is probably hand-vectorized, with a small working set such as yours you're working entirely from the cache and can reach throughput of up to 512 bytes per comparison (with AVX2). Assuming a moderate rate of 10 cycles per iteration, we can still compare >10<sup>10</sup> bytes/s. So your program should run in <1 s on moderate hardware.

Try this updated code instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    set<string> c;
    string s(100000,'a');
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) { // Add a digit here
        c.insert(s);
    }
    return c.size(); // use something from the set
}
```

With optimization on (`-O3`) this takes ~5 seconds to run on my system.

In other words yes, inserting into a binary tree has O(log n) complexity, but comparing a string has O(n) complexity. These n's aren't the same, in the case of a `map` it represents the map size, and in case of `string` - the length of the string.

In your particular case the map has just one element, so insertion is O(1). You get linear complexity O(n) purely from string comparisons, where *n* is *string_length * number_of_iterations*.